# Sentence Comparison: Ignore Words

Tags: php, regex

I need some help with sentence comparison.

```
    $answer = "This is the (correct and) acceptable answer. Content inside the parenthesis are ignored if not present in the user's answer. If it is present, it should not count against them.";
    $response = "This is the correct and acceptable answer. Content inside the parenthesis are ignored if not present in the user's answer. If it is present, it should not count against them.";

    echo "<strong>Acceptable Answer:</strong>";
    echo "<pre style='white-space:normal;'>$answer</pre><hr/>";
    echo "<strong>User's Answer:</strong>";
    echo "<pre>".$response."</pre>";

    // strip content in brackets
    $answer = preg_replace("/\([^)]*\)|[()]/", "", $answer);

    // strip punctuation
    $answer = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/", " ", $answer);
    $response = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/", " ", $response);

    $common = similar_text($answer, $response, $percent);
    $orgcount = strlen($answer);
    printf("The user's response has %d/$orgcount characters in common (%.2f%%).", $common, $percent);
```

Basically what I want to do is ignore parenthiseised words. For example, in the $answer string, *correct and* are in parenthesis - because of this, I don't want these words to count agains the user's response. So if the user has these words, it doesn't count against them. And if the user doesn't have these words, it doesn't count against them.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do `$answer` and `$response` contain after your `preg_replace` functions?  It looks like you are already stripping out anything that is not alpha-numeric and space.

Comment: _Count against them_ I mean it won't change the similarity percentage. So, if the user either has or doesn't have the parenthesized words, it won't change the percentage. However, if they don't have something that isn't parenthesized, it will affect the similarity percentage.

Comment: **$answer:** `This is the acceptable answer Content inside the parenthesis are ignored if not present in the user s answer If it is present it should not count against them`  **$response:** `This is the correct and acceptable answer Content inside the parenthesis are ignored if not present in the user s answer If it is present it should not count against them`

Comment: And how is your code currently failing?

Comment: @MikeM it currently affects the percentage with the parenthesized words. With the regex of removing parenthesized words, and the user has these words, it drops the percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I've wrote a solution, since it's a "long" process i though to put it in a function.
**EDIT:** After debugging it came out that `strpos()` was causing some trouble if the position was `0`, so i added an `OR` statement:

```
$answer = "(This) is the (correct and) acceptable answer. (random this will not count) Content inside the parenthesis are ignored if not present in the user's answer. If it is present, it should not count against them.";
$response = "This is the correct and acceptable answer. Content inside the parenthesis are ignored if not present in the user's answer. If it is present, it should not count against them.";

echo 'The user\'s response has '.round(compare($answer, $response),2).'% characters in common'; // The user's response has 100% characters in common

function compare($answer, $response){   
    preg_match_all('/\((?P<parenthesis>[^\)]+)\)/', $answer, $parenthesis);

    $catch = $parenthesis['parenthesis'];
    foreach($catch as $words){
        if(!strpos($response, $words) === false || strpos($response, $words) === 0){ // if it does exist then remove brackets
            $answer = str_replace('('.$words.')', $words, $answer);
        }else{ //if it does not exist remove the brackets with the words
            $answer = str_replace('('.$words.')', '', $answer);
        }
    }
    /* To sanitize */
    $answer = preg_replace(array('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '/ +/'), array(' ', ' '), $answer);
    $response = preg_replace(array('/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/', '/ +/'), array(' ', ' '), $response);
    $common = similar_text($answer, $response, $percent);
    return($percent);
}
```

Comment: Just tried it, and yes, unfortunately it still drops the percentage.

Comment: Of course the percentage will drop, since the response contains `correct and`. Maybe i didn't quite understand the issue ?

Comment: I don't want the percentage to drop if the words are enclosed between parenthesis and they exist in the user's response. If the words are not in parenthesis and they don't exist in the response, then the percentage should drop.

Comment: @Dutchcoffee ok, I'm close to a solution. Just one more question: if the words enclosed between parenthesis are not in the response, should it drop the percentage ?

Comment: If the words enclosed between parenthesis are not in the response, it should not drop the percentage. I greatly appreciate your assistance on this!

Comment: @Dutchcoffee I just edited my answer, take a look and tell me if it works to your expectations...

Comment: I concur with MikeM. I need to be able to enclose anything and have it not affect the response percentage.

Comment: Sorry guys, yet another revision :p

Comment: Hmm, if I change the `$answer` to: `(This is the correct and) acceptable (answer). (Random this will not count) Content inside the parenthesis are ignored if not present in the user's answer. If it is present, it should not count against them.`  

It deducts some percentage points even though the world `answer` is in parenthesis (but not in the user's answer)...it shouldn't deduct percentage points for this. My guess is because there are two `answer` in the string?

Comment: @Dutchcoffee I tried the now provided string and it gives me a 100% match

Comment: Try taking the first `"answer"` out of `$response` and it drops.

Comment: Ah yes, well that's all I can do for now. This will get rather complicated if I removed all the duplicates.